# The splitting field of $x^p-1 \in \mathbb{Q}[x] $ where p is odd prime, contains a unique subfield of index 2

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

I took particular case when p=3 then I find that $\mathbb{Q}$ is subfield of index 2 in this particular case.

I also find that  splitting field of given polynomial is $\mathbb{Q(a) }$ where a is pth root of unity such that a is not  1.

How can I find unique subfield of index 2 in general?

Comment: Your special case $p=3$ though correct, it is over simplified. "A group order 2 has a subgroup of index 2, namely the trivial subgroup" is not a hard statement. Try $p=5$ at least.

Comment: It isn't hard to compute the Galois group very explicitly in this case. Hint: a permutation is determined by where you send your $a$, and you can send it to any root. What does this imply about the Galois group?